Name of temporary table show up like commentary in VS Code
I'm using SQL Server with PHP in VSCode, when I need to create temporary tables as in the example below, part of the SQL looks like it was commented out.
SELECT * INTO #g2 FROM my_table

This part here #g2 FROM my_table is all grayed out, as if it were a normal comment, is there any way to disable this just for the SQL context?

This is a linting issue, so more of a bug. I would suggest raising it an a issue on either the repo for VS Code or whatever repo you are using for the linting of PHP. I would expect values within literal strings to not cause comments to be invoked. (though I can't reproduce with the built in linting for SQL or PHP, suggesting it it an extension issue)

I disabled all extensions before posting here, but I will post them in the VS repository. Thanks!

Can you show this in the context of the PHP code please?

Not sure if SQLServer supports backquoting table names like MySQL does, but if so, you can do that to "reset" the VSCode formatter. SELECT * INTO `#g2` FROM my_table;

@testing-for-ya your suggestion worked.
